# Is there a reason I shouldn't intentionaly hit walltime?

Tags: cluster-computing, qsub

I am submitting a job (via qsub) that is not in anyway the worse off for being killed part way through, and the more time it runs for the better. Results are output at it goes along.

It will be submitted to a large cluster that is well managed. It is safe to assume that whoever has control over the cluster has set it up in a reasonable and sensible way.

From my point of view it is more useful to tell it to loop more times than will fit inside walltime and let it be killed, than to tell it to loop less and have it finish before walltime. If it finished before walltime it did not do as many loops as it possibly could have done.

Is there any problem or annoyance caused by this approach? It's working well but I'm worried I could be upsetting someone.

Answer (score 0):

So I put this question to the administrators of my cluster. The answer I got was;

> Thanks for your query. I can see no reason that this would be an issue - simply ensuring you get as much run from you job as possible in the requested time.